# How to extract text from second link using previous webelement?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

I am using this code, but it's not working but xpath in the picture is correct. I am not allowed to use `(//h2//a[@class='question-link'])[2]` because I need to use previous webelement:

```
        driver.get("https://stackexchange.com/");
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2//a[@class='question-link']"));
        WebElement f=e.findElement(By.xpath(".[2]"));
        System.out.println(f.getText());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second element you want is just another element that is located by the first locator. The easiest way to do what you are asking is to change the first statement to use `.findElements()` (plural) and then get the second element returned.

```
List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h2//a[@class='question-link']"));
System.out.println(e.get(1).getText()); // index starts at 0 so 1 is the second element
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of again writing Webelement f write the complete xpath including [2] in Webelement e itself.

Comment: No I need to write **Webelement f**

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! Some more explanation and code would sure be helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example in Python using Selenium to extract the text from the second link using a previous WebElement:

from selenium import webdriver

## initialize the browser

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

## navigate to the website

driver.get("https://www.example.com")

## locate the previous WebElement

previous_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#element_id")

## locate the second link relative to the previous WebElement

second_link = previous_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[1]

## extract the text from the second link

text = second_link.text

## close the browser

driver.quit()

Note: Replace #element_id with the actual id of the previous WebElement and make sure to install the Selenium library if not already installed.

Comment: my question is about JAVA not **python**